# Automatic merge branch into master on successful build in travis

Tags: git, github, merge, travis-ci

I've trying to do a setup, where I use Travis CI
(http://www.travis-ci.org) to build and test my program each time I commit to GitHub. My GitHub setup is to have a master and a slave/test branch, which I commit to before merging into master. However, as of right now I'm doing the merging manually on GitHub.com, which I could like to automate, such that when a build is successful on Travis, I want to merge my slave/test branch into the master right away. Does anybody know how this is possible on Travis CI or another way of achieving this with Travis?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can prepare script which will use for merge your branches.
Travis set some useful environment variables which you can use in your script.

Merge script can look like:

```
if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" != "test" ]; then 
    exit 0;
fi

export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=...
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=...

git checkout master || exit
git merge "$TRAVIS_COMMIT" || exit
git push ... # here need some authorization and url
```

Next you can put in `.travis.yml`

```
after_success: ./merge_script.sh
```

More info:

- http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Environment-variables
- http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-lifecycle/

Comment: in my experience, commands like `git checkout some-branch` will fail in Travis-CI.